# prevent two objects in two identical lists from matching in java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I'm trying to make a program that randomly matches people in a list in order to figure out who is buying who a gift this year.

The problem I am running into is that certain people can't match up because they are married, for example, Deana and Pete can't match nor can Chris and Lindsay.

Here is what I have right now without trying to prevent these match ups. 
Thank you,

```
        String[] family = {"Jen", "Chris", "Lindsay", "Erica", "Deana", "Pete"};
    ArrayList people = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i<family.length; i++){
        people.add(family[i]);
    }

    int i=0;
    while (i != family.length) {
        int personTwo = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * people.size());
        String perTst = people.get(personTwo).toString();
        if((family[i] != perTst)){

            System.out.println(family[i] +" buys for " + people.get(personTwo));

            people.remove(personTwo);
            i++;
        }


    }
```

Comment: use the String equals() function when comparing strings in java here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: What are you having problems with?

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz Identity comparison is pretty safe in this case, unless the array can have duplicates.

Comment: FYI, if you properly declare `people` as `ArrayList<String>`, you won't have to call `toString()` later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a map of couples:

```
Map<String, String> couples = new HashMap<>();
couples.put("Deana", "Pete");
couples.put("Chris", "Lindsay");
```

Then update your `if` to check if they're a couple:

```
if(!family[i].equals(perTst)
        && !perTst.equals(couples.get(family[i]))
        && !family[i].equals(couples.get(perTst))) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm still pretty new to java and only touched on Maps very briefly.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that would be to create a map of people to a set of who they cannot be matched with. For example:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> notAllowed = new HashMap<>();
Set<String> deanaSet = new HashSet<>();
deanaSet.put("Pete");
Set<String> peteSet = new HashSet<>();
peteSet.put("Deana");
...
notAllowed.put("Deana", deanaSet);
notAllowed.put("Pete", peteSet);
```

Then you can just get the set of not allowed matches for each user and see if the person you're proposing adding is in the set of not allowed users.